# Pass limit and offset values through URL using Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I'm new on Resfully services and Lumen (Laravel micro-framework).

I want to pass the /books?limit=10&offset=5 parameters to the controller and set it on the json response and I can't figure out how.

**web.php**

```
$router->get('/books/', ['uses' => 'BooksController@index']);
```

**BooksController.php**

```
 public function index()
{

  $books = PartnersBooks::where('is_direct', '=', 1)
      ->with('direct')
      ->whereHas('direct', function ($query) {
          $query->enable()
          ->select(['id', 'book_id', 'name', 'devices', 'flow', 'restrictions', 'countries', 'targeting']);
      })
      ->offset(5) // This should have an default value until the user pass a value through url
      ->limit(30) // This should have an default value until the user pass a value through url
      ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
      ->get(['id', 'category', 'description']);

      $status = !is_null($books) ? 200 : 204;
      return response()->json($books, $status);
}
```

Could you please help me?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could to use the [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests) object to do that:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


public function index(Request $request)
{
    $limit = $request->input('limit');
    $offset = $request->input('offset');

    $books = PartnersBooks::where('is_direct', '=', 1)
      ->with('direct')
      ->whereHas('direct', function ($query) {
          $query->enable()
            ->select(['id', 'book_id', 'name', 'devices', 'flow', 'restrictions', 'countries', 'targeting']);
      })
      ->offset($offset) // This should have an default value until the user pass a value through url
      ->limit($limit) // This should have an default value until the user pass a value through url
      ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
      ->get(['id', 'category', 'description']);

     $status = !is_null($books) ? 200 : 204;
     return response()->json($books, $status);
}
```

Comment: `$request->input()` also accepts 2nd parameter for the default value. So you could set a default like that: `$offset = $request->input('offset', 5)`. And similar for limit.

Comment: Done! Thank you!